# Moving uv to another similar object

Tags: uv

I have model I made with photogrammtery specifically using photocatch. Its a coffee bean, photo catch creates insane looking meshes so I tried to remesh it with instant meshes and made something much more simple and uniform that came out pretty well.

The issue is that the simple mesh model doesn't have the texture anymore so I need to move the UV from the complex model to the simpler one but I am having some trouble figuring out how to do this. Chatgpt has not been helpful and I am also somewhat new to blender so forgive my noobism.

I just want to know how to properly transfer and align the texture onto the new model. I tried the transfer data modifier but was confused on the settings and the direction Chatgpt gave me may have been wrong because nothing happened.

I am on Blender 4.0 also if that makes a difference or not

Edit:
The uv that was created in PhotoCatch (Photogrammetry program I use) is a sqaure 8192x8192 its not a uv like the ones blender makes: https://imgur.com/a/4pe1Xil

Here is the models im trying to get the texture from the left model to put on the lower poly right one: https://imgur.com/a/aGsfyIa

Comment: Bake the DIffuse from the original object to the new one?

Comment: That doesnt work for some reason. It seems like the baking failes